# EWS subscriptions "falling off"

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm working on a synchronization system, which synchronizes Outlook with another system.

I am subscribing to around 600 mailbox calendars in an Exchange 2013 server.

When the subscription is done, I pull the users entire mailboxes, to perform a full synchronization with the other system. This works well.

**Now the problem:**
A large portion of the 600 mailboxes are not delivering push notifications to the system, when changes are made to their calendar.

Have any of you run into similar problems, or got any idea to why this is happening?

Is it possible to monitor something on the Exchange server, that can tell me something about the subscriptions?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to increase the diagnostic logging for EWS https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335139(v=exchg.141).aspx and then any errors,warning with subscription will be logged to the Event Log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting "heartbeat" notifications and keeping track of whether any are missed?  EWS Push subscriptions can be "lost" by Exchange over time, and if your code is not watching for MBs that are not getting their Status Events, then you will miss change notifications.  In the event you miss a Status Event (and usually it's good to tread lightly, e.g. if you expect hearbeats within 5 minutes, don't really consider it lost until the 6th minute), you'll need to re-subscribe the MB.

Comment: Nope i'm not doing any of that. Are heartbeat events something that can be set up using EWS?

Comment: They are essentially set up by the SubscribeToPushNotifications() call with the "frequency" integer which specifies the interval in minutes.  Let's say you set it to 5.  So within 5 minutes from the subscribe or the last notification, if there have been no events to notify your listening URL about, you will get a Status Event, which is essentially a heartbeat.  So you have to set a time stamp on whatever object you are using to manage each subscription.  When any notification/heartbeat comes in, set the time stamp.  Then periodically check your objects for time stamps older than, say, 6 mins.

Answer (score -1):

Are you aware of the throttling settings on the exchange server? They can limit the number of open connections or subscriptions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458789%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx#bk_throttling